# C# DataSet Designer - AccesDB - Combine two rows into one

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2016

I need your help with an SQL query, that I am trying to build in C# Dataset Query Builder...

```sql
SELECT HouseHold.HHID, Client.FIRST_NAME, Client.LAST_NAME 
FROM ((Client 
INNER JOIN HouseHold_Client ON Client.CID = HouseHold_Client.CID) 
INNER JOIN HouseHold ON HouseHold_Client.HHID = HouseHold.HHID)
```

Above code gives me the list of all HouseHolds (their ID) with Clients belonging to them:

```
HHID  |  FIRST_NAME |  LAST_NAME
------------------------------
1     |  Penelope   |  Grant
1     |  Brian      |  Dyer
2     |  James      |  Newman
2     |  Richard    |  Parsons
```

.. but I can't figure out how to get people belonging to same HouseHold to show up on the same line, like this for a Data Grid View later on:

```
HHID | I_FIRST_NAME | I_LAST_NAME | II_FIRST_NAME | II_LAST_NAME
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1    | Penelope     | Grant       | Brian         | Dyer
2    | James        | Newman      | Richard       | Parsons
```

I have found loads of very similar questions, but very few had the same exact problem to solve. The ones (one or two) that really had the same problem and it had a solution, I just couldn't twist around my problem.

Any help is very much appreciated...
Thank you very much,
AD

Comment: Are there always maximum 2 persons per household?

Comment: Yes... Minimum 1, and Maximum 2. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 2 persons per household, you can use the trick to get the minimum and maximum client Id per household. This is done in a subquery.

```
SELECT
    X.HHID,
    C1.FIRST_NAME AS I_FIRST_NAME, C1.LAST_NAME AS I_LAST_NAME,
    C2.FIRST_NAME AS II_FIRST_NAME, C2.LAST_NAME AS II_LAST_NAME
FROM
    ((  SELECT
            HHID, Min(CID) AS MinCId, IIf(Max(CID)=Min(CID), Null, Max(CID))  AS MaxCId
        FROM HouseHold_Client
        GROUP BY HHID
    ) X
    INNER JOIN Client AS C1
        ON X.MinCId = C1.CID)
    LEFT JOIN Client AS C2
        ON X.MaxCId = C2.CID;
```

The purpose of the `IIf()` expression is to output the maximum client Id only if it is different from the minimum client Id. To also return a record when `MaxCId` is `Null`, a `LEFT JOIN` is required on `C2`.

I did not join the `HouseHold` table here, since we only need the `HHID` from it, which is also available in `HouseHold_Client`. You can of course join it as well, if you need other columns from it.

---

Subquery:

```
(  SELECT
        HHID, Min(CID) AS MinCId, IIf(Max(CID)=Min(CID), Null, Max(CID))  AS MaxCId
    FROM HouseHold_Client
    GROUP BY HHID
) X
```

Subqueries must be enclosed in parentheses and be given a name (here `X`). `X` acts as a normal table having the columns `HHID`, `MinCId` and `MaxCId` in the main query. It is grouped by `HHID`. I.e., it returns one row per `HHID`. `Min(CID)` returns the smallest `CID` and `Max(CID)` largest `CID` per `HHID`.

In the case where you have 2 clients per `HHID`, this means that `Min` and `Max` will yield these 2 clients. If you have only 1 client, then both `Min` and `Max` will return the same client. If this is the case, then the `IIf` will return `Null` instead of `Max(CID)` to avoid returning twice the same client.

Comment: Hi Olivier... Your solution gives me exactly, what I needed. It is still too much for me to comprehend... Well Done and Thank you.. Why does Designer say: "The wizard detected the following problems when configuring the TableAdapter: 'Fill'. Details: ! Generated SELECT Statement. Error in list of function arguments '=' not recognized"., also same about ')' and 'LEFT'. "Unable to parse query text." ?Although it gives me all this, it gives me the expected result... Thank you very much again...

Comment: Sometime manually constructed commands can only be viewed in SQL view, but not in designer view.